# Как сделать открытие ссылки через браузер в Android Studio Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Столкнулся с тем, что не могу реализовать открытие ссылки в Kotlin Android Studio. Пробовал с помощью khttp.get(), но безуспешно. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.net.Uri
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.example.telegram.R
import com.example.telegram.database.USER
import com.example.telegram.ui.screens.contacts.ContactsFragment
import com.example.telegram.ui.screens.groups.AddContactsFragment
import com.example.telegram.ui.screens.settings.SettingsFragment
import com.example.telegram.utilits.APP_ACTIVITY
import com.example.telegram.utilits.downloadAndSetImage
import com.example.telegram.utilits.replaceFragment
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeader
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeaderBuilder
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.DividerDrawerItem
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileDrawerItem
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.IDrawerItem
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.AbstractDrawerImageLoader
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.DrawerImageLoader

class AppDrawer {

val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"))
private lateinit var mDrawer: Drawer
private lateinit var mHeader: AccountHeader
private lateinit var mDrawerLayout: DrawerLayout
private lateinit var mCurrentProfile:ProfileDrawerItem

fun create() {
    initLoader()
    createHeader()
    createDrawer()
    mDrawerLayout = mDrawer.drawerLayout
}

fun disableDrawer() {
    mDrawer.actionBarDrawerToggle?.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = false
    APP_ACTIVITY.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
    APP_ACTIVITY.mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        APP_ACTIVITY.supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
    }
}

fun enableDrawer() {
    APP_ACTIVITY.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
    mDrawer.actionBarDrawerToggle?.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = true
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
    APP_ACTIVITY.mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        mDrawer.openDrawer()
    }
}

private fun createDrawer() {
    mDrawer = DrawerBuilder()
        .withActivity(APP_ACTIVITY)
        .withToolbar(APP_ACTIVITY.mToolbar)
        .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
        .withSelectedItem(-1)
        .withAccountHeader(mHeader)
        .addDrawerItems(
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(100)
                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                .withName("Стварыць групу")
                .withSelectable(false)
                .withIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_create_groups),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(101)
                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                .withName("Стварыць сакрэтны чат")
                .withSelectable(false)
                .withIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_secret_chat),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(102)
                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                .withName("Стварыць канал")
                .withSelectable(false)
                .withIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_create_channel),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(103)
                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                .withName("Кантакты")
                .withSelectable(false)
                .withIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_contacts),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(104)
                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                .withName("Званкі")
                .withSelectable(false)
                .withIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_phone),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(105)
                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                .withName("Выбранае")
                .withSelectable(false)
                .withIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_favorites),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(106)
                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                .withName("Налады")
                .withSelectable(false)
                .withIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_settings),
            DividerDrawerItem(),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(108)
                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                .withName("Запрасіць сяброў")
                .withSelectable(false)
                .withIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_invate),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(109)
                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                .withName("Пытанні аб БМВ")
                .withSelectable(false)
                .withIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_help),
            DividerDrawerItem(),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(108)
                .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                .withName("Арфаграфічная вясёлка")
                .withSelectable(false)
                .withIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_invate)
        ).withOnDrawerItemClickListener(object : Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                drawerItem: IDrawerItem<*>
            ): Boolean {
                clickToItem(position)
                return false
            }
        }).build()

}


private fun startActivity(browserIntent: Intent) {
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"))
}


private fun clickToItem(position: Int){
     when (position) {
         1 -> replaceFragment(AddContactsFragment())
         7 -> replaceFragment(SettingsFragment())
         4 -> replaceFragment(ContactsFragment())
         12 -> startActivity(browser)
     }
 }


private fun createHeader() {
    mCurrentProfile = ProfileDrawerItem()
        .withName(USER.fullname)
        .withEmail(USER.phone)
        .withIcon(USER.photoUrl)
        .withIdentifier(200)
    mHeader = AccountHeaderBuilder()
        .withActivity(APP_ACTIVITY)
        .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header)
        .addProfiles(
            mCurrentProfile
        ).build()
}

fun updateHeader(){
    mCurrentProfile
        .withName(USER.fullname)
        .withEmail(USER.phone)
        .withIcon(USER.photoUrl)

    mHeader.updateProfile(mCurrentProfile)

}

private fun initLoader(){
    DrawerImageLoader.init(object : AbstractDrawerImageLoader() {
        override fun set(imageView: ImageView, uri: Uri, placeholder: Drawable) {
            imageView.downloadAndSetImage(uri.toString())
        }
    })
}
}
```

Comment: `val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);`

Comment: А, извините за столь глупый вопрос, но я новичок, почему мне подчеркивает красным startActivity? Эта функция должна быть где-то создана?

Comment: Это метод класса `Context`. Т.е. надо вызывать в активити этот код, например. Или на к-л явно полученном экземпляре этого класса.

Comment: А в чём может быть проблема, если ничего не происходит при нажатии на кнопку, хотя сделал, как по примеру?

Comment: Видимо что то не так написали. Покажите код через правку вопроса

Comment: Может нужно создать второй Activity?

Comment: Вы создали метод startActivity который ничего не делает. Вместо этого вам надо использовать метод класса Context. Покажите весь файл с кодом - возможно получится сказать что именно вам надо исправить. А то, мне думается, что `использовать метод класса Context` вам ни о чём не скажет

Comment: И в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас очень странный код. Судя по всему заработать должно так: `APP_ACTIVITY.startActivity(browserIntent)`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь